# How to get rid of all html tags and its content within a string in C#

Tags: c#, html, string, tags

I want to use string manipulation within a string instead of bringing the string into a richTextBox. My programme at the moment does string manipulation within a richTextBox. How can I do the same without using a richTextBox?

The problem I’m having is that the action gets triggered when something has been changed within the richTextBox. So when something gets changed, programme will scan the rich text box for html tags and simply get rid of all of them. How can this be done, presumably faster, without using a richTextBox?

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int token = -1;
        int token2 = -1;

        foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("<") || line.Contains(">"))
            {
                while (richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("<") > -1 && richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(">") > -1)
                {
                    token = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("<");
                    token2 = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(">", token) + 1;
                    string clip = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(token, token2 - token);
                    richTextBox1.Select(token, token2 - token);
                    if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(richTextBox1.Text.Substring(richTextBox1.SelectionStart, richTextBox1.SelectionLength), " ");
                    }
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(" ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i think you can write function to check text entered in richtext box and call when required.

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if(your condition)
            {
            CheckRichTextEntered(richTextBox1.Text)
            }
        }


        public void CheckRichTextEntered(string RichBoxText)
        {
                int token = -1;
                int token2 = -1;

                foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("<") || line.Contains(">"))
                    {
                        while (richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("<") > -1 && richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(">") > -1)
                        {
                            token = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("<");
                            token2 = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(">", token) + 1;
                            string clip = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(token, token2 - token);
                            richTextBox1.Select(token, token2 - token);
                            if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
                            {
                                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(richTextBox1.Text.Substring(richTextBox1.SelectionStart, richTextBox1.SelectionLength), " ");
                            }
                            richTextBox1.AppendText(" ");
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```